# GStreamer equivalent to FFmpeg Remap

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I currently have an FFmpeg command that looks like the following (i.e. uses the remap filter operation):

```
ffmpeg -y -i camera.mp4 -i x.pgm -i y.pgm -lavfi remap output.mp4
```

I am now interested in doing this same processing in real-time using GStreamer.

Does an equivalent GStreamer element exist?

If not, is there a way to use the FFmpeg remap filter inside of the GStreamer framework?